# JavaScript objects not inheriting from prototype chain

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype

I'm having trouble defining prototypes for my constructor functions in Chrome 21. I'm working on a big project in which I'm trying to implement a pseudo-class-based structure (hence the 'subclass' properties) with some very loose data encapsulation, but I'm relatively new to prototyping and inheritance in JavaScript and can't figure out what's wrong. There are other vaguely similar threads on StackOverflow, but nothing that solves this problem.

Here are the constructors I'm working with:

```
function Root()
{
  this._subclass = "Root";
  this.subclass = function(){
    return this._subclass;
  };

  this._date;
  this.date = function(){
    return this._date;
  };
}

function CustomDateTime()
{
  this._subclass = "CustomDateTime";
  this._value = new Date();
}
CustomDateTime.prototype = new Root;

function CurrentDate()
{
  this._subclass = "CurrentDate";
}
CurrentDate.prototype = new CustomDateTime;
```

Intuitively, it seems to me that I should be able to do this (because subclass() is defined in the `Root` constructor):

```
var now = new CurrentDate();
alert(now.subclass()); // should alert "CurrentDate"
```

but on running the script I get a `TypeError: Object #<CurrentDate> has no method 'subclass'`. Additionally, if I change the `CurrentDate` constructor to include this alert:

```
function CurrentDate()
{
  alert(this._subclass);
  this._subclass = "CurrentDate";
}
CurrentDate.prototype = new CustomDateTime;
```

the resultant message is `undefined`.

If instead I assign `var now = new CustomDateTime()`, calling the subclass() method returns "CustomDateTime" just as intended. I've also defined another constructor, `ModelObject`, whose prototype is set to `Root` and subclass() performs as intended on those objects as well.

What I'm getting out of this is that the CurrentDate constructor is being left out of the CurrentDate : CustomDateTime : Root chain and simply being called as a standalone constructor- objects created using this function don't seem to be inheriting from the prototype assigned to the CurrentDate function object.

Is this not the correct way to use JavaScript prototypes? Again, it seems to me that this should be going very smoothly..

Comment: Your first code example `alert(now.subclass());` works correctly. There is no "has no method" error. http://jsfiddle.net/WL5tC/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 'gray state is coming' for the response. Seeing the code run properly in jsfiddle taught me that, when you include multiple  tags on a .html page, you have to put the tags in the order of their prototypical inheritance. If the CurrentDate  is before the CustomDateTime , the CustomDateTime function has not yet been defined when `CurrentDate.prototype` is assigned.